# Deep neural-network with backpropagation implementation does not work - python

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, neural-network, backpropagation, softmax

I want to implement a multilayer NN with backpropagation. I have been trying for days, but it simply does not work. It is extremely clear in my head how it is supposed to work, I have streamline my code to be as simple as possible but I can't do it. It's probably something stupid, but I cannot see it.

- The implementation I have done is with an input layer of 784 (28x28), two (L) hidden layers of 300 and an output of 10 classes. I have a bias in every layer (except last...)
- The output activation is softmax and the hidden activation is ReLU.
- I use mini batches of 600 examples over a dataset of 60k examples with 50 to 500 epoches.

Here the core of my code:

Preparation:

```
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fashion_mnist = keras.datasets.fashion_mnist
(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = fashion_mnist.load_data()

L = 2
K = len(np.unique(train_labels))
lr = 0.001
nb_epochs = 50
node_per_hidden_layer = 300
nb_batches = 100
W = []
losses_test = []

X_train = np.reshape(train_images, (train_images.shape[0], train_images.shape[1]*train_images.shape[2]))
X_test = np.reshape(test_images, (test_images.shape[0], train_images.shape[1]*train_images.shape[2]))

Y_train = np.zeros((train_labels.shape[0], K))
Y_train[np.arange(Y_train.shape[0]), train_labels] = 1

Y_test = np.zeros((test_labels.shape[0], K))
Y_test[np.arange(Y_test.shape[0]), test_labels] = 1

W.append(np.random.normal(0, 0.01, (X_train.shape[1]+1, node_per_hidden_layer)))
for i in range(L-1):
    W.append(np.random.normal(0, 0.01, (node_per_hidden_layer+1, node_per_hidden_layer)))
W.append(np.random.normal(0, 0.01, (node_per_hidden_layer+1, K)))
```

Helper function:

```
def softmax(z):
    exp = np.exp(z - z.max(1)[:,np.newaxis])
    return np.array(exp / exp.sum(1)[:,np.newaxis])


def softmax_derivative(z):
    sm = softmax(z)
    return sm * (1-sm)


def ReLU(z):
    return np.maximum(z, 0)


def ReLU_derivative(z):
    return (z >= 0).astype(int)


def get_loss(y, y_pred):
    return -np.sum(y * np.log(y_pred))
```

fitting

```
def fit():
    minibatch_size = len(X_train) // nb_batches

    for epoch in range(nb_epochs):
        permutaion = list(np.random.permutation(X_train.shape[0]))
        X_shuffle = X_train[permutaion]
        Y_shuffle = Y_train[permutaion]
        print("Epoch----------------", epoch)

        for batche in range(0, X_shuffle.shape[0], minibatch_size):
            Z = [None] * (L + 2)
            a = [None] * (L + 2)
            delta = [None] * (L + 2)
            X = X_train[batche:batche+minibatch_size]
            Y = Y_shuffle[batche:batche+minibatch_size]

            ### forward propagation
            a[0] = np.append(X, np.ones((minibatch_size, 1)), axis=1)
            for i in range(L):
                Z[i + 1] = a[i] @ W[i]
                a[i + 1] = np.append(ReLU(Z[i+1]), np.ones((minibatch_size, 1), dtype=int), axis=1)

            Z[-1] = a[L] @ W[L]
            a[-1] = softmax(Z[-1])

            ### back propagation
            delta[-1] = (Y - a[-1]) * softmax_derivative(Z[-1])
            for i in range(L, 0, -1):
                delta[i] = (delta[i+1] @ W[i].T)[:,:-1] * ReLU_derivative(Z[i])

            for i in range(len(W)):
                g = a[i].T @ delta[i+1] / minibatch_size
                W[i] = W[i] + lr * g

        get_loss_on_test()
```

loss

```
def get_loss_on_test():
    Z_test = [None] * (L + 2)
    a_test = [None] * (L + 2)

    a_test[0] = np.append(X_test, np.ones((len(X_test), 1)), axis=1)
    for i in range(L):
        Z_test[i + 1] = a_test[i] @ W[i]
        a_test[i + 1] = np.append(ReLU(Z_test[i+1]), np.ones((len(X_test), 1)), axis=1)

    Z_test[-1] = a_test[L] @ W[L]
    a_test[-1] = softmax(Z_test[-1])

    losses_test.append(get_loss(Y_test, a_test[-1]))
```

main

```
losses_test.clear()
fit()
plt.plot(losses_test)
plt.show()
```

If you want to see it in my notebook with an example of losses graph, here the link: https://github.com/beurnii/INF8225/blob/master/tp2/jpt.ipynb

If you want more details on my assignment, this is part 1b (page 2 for english):
https://github.com/beurnii/INF8225/blob/master/tp2/INF8225_TP2_2020.pdf

Comment: WHY does it not work? Be specific. Simply saying it doesn't work doesn't help anyone determine what the problem is.

Comment: One thing that stands out to me is the precision. You're using int. Please use floating point to maintain precision. This may be the reason why the backprop isn't working. Also, why are you adding the gradients? This is gradient descent so you should be subtracting the gradients at each iteration.